# Playing multiple sound tracks at once from mp4 video HTML5 web player

Tags: html, html5-video

I've got a mp4 file with one video track and several sound tracks. When i try to open the file in  in HTML5 it only play's audio track one. Is it a way to override the the web player to play all sound tracks at once?